# How do I write a conditional for whether a section contains entries?

Tags: templating, conditional

I've got a blog section on a page but want to hide it if there are no blogs.

```
{% set blog = craft.entries.section('blog').limit(5) %}
{% if blog !='' %}
  <div class="something">
    {% for entry in blog %}
      ...
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your blog variable is an [ElementCriteriaModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel), which can be treated like an iterable array:

```
{% if blog|length %}
    Content
{% endif %}
```